# cyclically generate an array of objects using a template

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array of objects like this:

```
[{key: 4214, value: 'example'}, ...etc
```

And i have some kind of template, that i want to use for generate a new array for objects.

```
{type: 1, blocks: []} //one item in blocks
{type: 2, blocks: []} //two items in blocks arr
{type: 3, blocks: []} //four items in blocks arr
```

I need to create an array based on a template, using data from an existing array.
In each of the templates `type`s a limited specified number of objects can fit into the `blocks` object. When the loop creates all three types from the template, it must start over from type one. In `type: 1` one object, two in `type: 2`, and four in `type: 3`

For example, the effect I want to achieve is the creation of new array from this `[{key: 1}, {key: 2}, {key: 3}]`
to this `[{type: 1, blocks: [{key: 1}]}, {type: 2, blocks: [{key: 2}, {key: 3}]}]`

If there were more objects, the next one object in new array will be `type: 3`, which `blocks` will contain 4 elements. And then, it starts again from `type: 1`. As a result, an array of any size must be transformed according to the logic of the template. sorry for my language, this is a super complicated explanation for me. if something is not clear, I will answer almost instantly

Answer (score 1):

You can implement based on `7 items` as one unit as follows.

```js
const input = [{key: 1}, {key: 2}, {key: 3}, {key: 4}, {key: 5}, {key: 6}, {key: 7}, {key: 8}, {key: 9}];
const result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i += 7) {
  const item = [];
  
  // Add Type1
  item.push({
    type: 1,
    blocks: [ input[i] ]
  });
  
  // Add Type2
  if (i + 1 < input.length) {
    item.push({
      type: 2,
      blocks: [ input[i + 1] ]
    });
  }
  if (i + 2 < input.length) {
    item[1].blocks.push(input[i + 2]);
  }
  
  // Add Type3
  if (i + 3 < input.length) {
    item.push({
      type: 3,
      blocks: [ input[i + 3] ]
    });
  }
  for (let subI = i + 4; subI < Math.min(i + 7, input.length); subI ++) {
    item[2].blocks.push(input[subI]);
  }
  
  result.push(...item);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: omg, really simple when you see a realized decision. thank you!